# symfony2 tutorial - generate bundle

Tags: php, symfony, bundle, symfony-2.1

I am new to symfony2 but not to symfony.  I am currently doing [the symblog tutorial](http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/docs/configuration-and-templating.html#bundles-symfony2-building-blocks).  Its going ok so far however I have come a little stuck on the generate bundle?

The tutorial says to run the following command

```
php app/console generate:bundle --namespace=Blogger/BlogBundle --format=yml
```

After completing that it should add reference/generate code to the bundle in the

- app/AppKernel.php
- app/config/routing.yml

However it has not added anything?... I'm a bit confused?  The console outputs the following but the code references to the bundle have not been generated in the files

```
Welcome to the Symfony2 bundle generator  



Your application code must be written in bundles. This command helps
you generate them easily.

Each bundle is hosted under a namespace (like Acme/Bundle/BlogBundle).
The namespace should begin with a "vendor" name like your company name, your
project name, or your client name, followed by one or more optional category
sub-namespaces, and it should end with the bundle name itself
(which must have Bundle as a suffix).

See http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html#index-1 for more
details on bundle naming conventions.

Use / instead of \  for the namespace delimiter to avoid any problem.

Bundle namespace [Blogger/BlogBundle]:
```

Comment: Be careful, this tutorial is for sf2.0.x. Which version are you using?

Comment: 2.1.7 - Maybe im calling the wrong command or using it wrong?

Comment: newer version of symfony behaves differently from what the tutorial expects.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use this without interaction . then it won't ask you anything

```
php app/console generate:bundle --namespace=Blogger/BlogBundle --format=yml --no-interaction
```

Comment: This is the best answer.  very concise.  The tutorial should have this command line.

Answer (score 6):

From `generate:bundle --help`

If you want to disable any user interaction, use --no-interaction but don't forget to pass all needed options:

```
php app/console generate:bundle --namespace=Acme/BlogBundle --dir=src [--bundle-name=...] --no-interaction
```

I have bash functions for these long commands.

```
genbundle () {
    php app/console generate:bundle --namespace=$1/$2Bundle --bundle-name=$2Bundle --dir=src/ --format=yml
}
```

You can use it like this: "genbundle Acme Blog", It'll create a BlogBundle in the Acme app.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood what's going on correctly, you have to go on the process. It's step-by-step where you answer the questions. Keep answering everything asked, and then the console will tell when it created the bundle.

Note: the value in [...] are the default value if you just press enter when the console asks you something.

Answer (score 0):

Old Command:

```
php app/console generate:bundle --namespace=Blogger/BlogBundle --format=yml --no-interaction
```

In new symfony version 3.1.4, **"app/console"** is no more working.
Instead add **"bin/console"** in above command

So the New command will be

```
php bin/console generate:bundle --namespace=Blogger/BlogBundle --format=yml --no-interaction
```